# How to submite image value from images when i click on the image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, input, web-crawler

so I built crawler that crawl all the data in the link from the value so I need a way when clicking on the image the value of the image go to output to `$_POST['']`, and how?

```
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

    $furl = 'https://hentaifox.com';

    $res = $client->request('GET', $furl);

    $html = ''.$res->getBody();

    $crawler = new Crawler($html);

    $url_f = $crawler->filter('#content .galleries_overview .item')->each(function(crawler $node, $i) {
     //echo $node->html();
        $image = $node->filter('img')->attr('src');
        $src = $node->filter('a')->attr('href');
        $href = 'https://hentaifox.com/'. $src;

    ?>

    <form method="post" id="manga">
        <input type="image" name="<?php echo $src ?>" src="<?php echo $image ?>" width="120" height="168" value="<?php echo $href ?>">
    </form>

    <?php }); ?>
```

Comment: Crawlers usually do not post anything, they download stuff. See: [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: i know that i only need the value of the image the i click